# Type Casting JSON & Bigint

Tags: laravel

I am trying to SUM JSON value + Integer value using laravel query builder but unable to do type casting error or maybe I am doing something wrong while writing the query.

```
Data saved in DB
comments: 100
fb_reactions: {"love":0,"like":8,"wow":0,"haha":0,"sad":0,"total":8,"angry":0} 

$content = Content::select('id','social_id','comments','fb_reactions',DB::raw('SUM(fb_reactions->total+comments) as appreciation'))->groupBy('id');
```

It should give appreciation=108

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is a database function that typically works on multiple *rows* of data, not data in the same row.  You're better off doing simple addition on the model instance and not in the database.

Add an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) to your model:

```php
// Content.php

protected $appends = ['appreciation'];           // auto append to the model
protected $casts = ['fb_reactions' => 'array'];  // auto cast json column to array

public function getAppreciationAttribute() {
    return $this->comments + $this->fb_reactions['total'];
}
```